# How can I format the text inside <input type="text"> to create a bounding box/ tag system like gmail, SO

Tags: jquery

I'm building a bounding box, bounding boxes are used on gmail, when you write a contact, it appears a bounding box.

Another example is YouTube, when you write tags.

I'm trying to create a similar script, but I'm having a little trouble here.

I want to put my script inside a input box, but the problem is that, when i use html tags, it doesnt read my script, example:

Here my HTML code:

```
<label>Tags</label>
<input type="text"  id="tags" class="tagstype" name="tags" maxlength="230">
```

And my JavaSript code

```
$('#tags').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 32) {
        var tx = $('#tags').val();
        if (tx) {
            $(this).val(tx+'[X]');
            closer();
        }
    }
});
});
```

It's working without html tags, but when i put some html tags, using this way

```
$('#tags').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 32) {
        var tx = $('#tags').val();
        if (tx) {
            $(this).val('<a>'tx+'[X]</a>');
            closer();
        }
    }
});
});
```

It doesn't show  the result of the  code, it only shows the tags.

I'm new at jQuery, is there any way to show the tags?

Comment: Instead of `<input>` Use `<div>` with Property: `contentEditable="true"` And you'll achieve what you want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a Look at:

## ***[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vedant_Terkar/LZZ5w/3/)***

This Does Exactly What You want, Though Modifications are needed I thought it will be useful for you to start your work.

In this I've taken a `<div>` instead of `<input>` and binded your `code` to that `div`.
I've set `contentEditable=true` inside that div so **it'll not work in IE(version<9)**.

If Browser Compatibility is an issue, then you better use plugin.

In that fiddle if you enter comma `,` separated `tagNames` and then press `shift+Enter` it'll automatically format your tags. also I've modified your `[x]` to `close button` which will delete that tag.

You may press `shift+enter` after supplying any input.

To use these values in actual `<form>` I've created a `hidden` input there, which needs modification in `JS` 
That is when Tags are formatted then it'll save their actual values in that `hidden input` which then can be used in `server side script`..

Hope it'll serve as an starting step, and will let you design your own code.

Inform me if you need more assistance. Cheers :-).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put HTML inside the value of an `input`.

To achieve what you're trying to do you will need to use a tag plugin, for example: http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/

There are plenty of others though, Google for `jquery tag plugin` to find them.

Comment: Of course you can put HTML in the value of an input box, it will just not be rendered as HTML.

Comment: @davidkonrad exactly. I don't see how that confused you?